# Solving systems of congruences

Tags: number-theory

I need to find if a solution exists.
\begin{align}
s &\equiv 2 \mod 21 \\
s &\equiv1 \mod 91 .
\end{align}

$s=21x+2$ and $s=91y+1$. Then $21x-91y=-1$. Consider $21x+91y=1$.

I found the $\operatorname{gcd}$ of $91$ and $21$ to be $7$. So Is there no solution since $\operatorname{gcd}(91,21) \neq 1$?

Comment: Yes.  $21x - 91y = 7(3x - 13y) = -1$ therefore (3x - 13y) = -1/7 which is clearly impossible if x and y are integers.  [Although it is sufficient to say 7 divides 21 and 91 and thus 21x - 91y but 7 does not divide -1]